# In a list, how to separate each string (with mixed special characters) into a single character?

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, list, nltk

Suppose, I want to split the following list into single character.

```
mylist = [('dog', 'camel'), ('horse'), ('List_of_people_saved_by_Oskar'), 'mouse_bear', 'lion tiger rabbit', 'ant']
```

This is what I have tried so far:

```
L1 = [animal for word in mylist for animal in word.split('_')]
print(L1)
```

Output should looks like:

```
`['dog', 'camel', 'horse', 'List', 'of', 'people', 'saved', 'by', 'Oskar', 'mouse', 'bear', 'lion', 'tiger' 'rabbit', 'ant']`
```

But I am getting an error:

```
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'split'
```

Comment: what counts as a *special character*?

Comment: Sorry I didn't get you

Comment: apart from space (`' '`) and underscore (`'_'`) what more can there be?

Comment: Only `Space` and `Underscore` is there. Apart from this, the list may have paired string like, `('dog', 'camel')`.

Comment: You want the code to be specific to the given input or for anything that comes it's way? Also, can the input be different than the ones you have already provided?

Comment: @Devanshu. The input format is similar to the above. There is no more combinations for the specified input. Yeah I want code to be specific to the given input. Any suggestion is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `re.findall(r'[^_ ]+', word)` instead to split the underscore or space-delimited words. Also add another comprehension layer to flatten the possible tuples of strings:

```
import re
L1 = [animal for item in mylist for word in (item if isinstance(item, (tuple, list)) else (item,)) for animal in re.findall(r'[^_ ]+', word)]
```

`L1` would become:

```
['dog', 'camel', 'horse', 'List', 'of', 'people', 'saved', 'by', 'Oskar', 'mouse', 'bear', 'lion', 'tiger', 'rabbit', 'ant']
```

Comment: Thanks @blhsing. What is `re.findall(r'[^_ ]+', word)` is about?

Comment: Suppose I have a word somewhat like this, for Example: `aspect-oriented.program`. How to deal this using regular expression `re`. The output should be a list having `['aspect', 'oriented', 'program']`

Comment: `re.findall` finds all the substrings matching the given regex in a list, and the regex pattern here matches a sequence of characters that are neither `_` nor ` `. Using `re.findall` is safer than using `re.split` because if you did `re.split(r'[_ ]', word)` then you may get empty strings when the input starts or ends with the delimiter or has double underscores or double spaces.

Comment: If you want to make dot a delimiter as well, simply add it to the regex pattern so you would do `re.findall(r'[^_ .]+', word)` instead.

Comment: Got it. I need to simply add the delimiter, without any comma in between. Right?

Comment: So, for the word `aspect-oriented.program`, I need to update your suggestion as `re.findall(r'[^_ .-]+', word)`. Is this right?

Comment: Yes that's right. If you have more delimiters to add, do always keep the dash at either the front or the last of character class like you're doing right now so that it wouldn't be interpreted as a range of characters as in `[a-z]`.

Comment: Thanks a ton @blhsing

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181936/discussion-between-m-s-and-blhsing).

Answer (score 1):

You just mixed up what goes where.

```
[animal.split('_') for word in mylist for animal in word]
```

There's an extra problem that `("horse")` is not a tuple; `("horse",)` is. Thus, `("horse")` is merely `"horse"` in parentheses, and `for animal in word` will enumerate the individual letters in `"horse"` instead of giving you back one `"horse"` animal.

If you wish to split by other characters than `_`, you can use `re.split` and a character class:

```
import re
[re.split(r'[_ ]', animal) for word in mylist for animal in word]
```

If you actually intended for the non-paired animals to *not* be tuples, then you will have to specially handle those cases:

```
[re.split(r'[_ ]', animal)
    for word in mylist
    for animal in (word if isinstance(word, tuple) else (word,))]
```

Comment: this does not seem to work. `'_'` is not the only delimiter.

Comment: @Ev.Kounis Unfortunately, I can only go by what is actually written in the question. There was code; I addressed it.

Comment: If the confusion of the OP guided the answers in this site, there wouldn't be much use to it (imho ofc).

Comment: Thanks @Amadan It helps!

Answer (score 1):

Well here's a more readable code, Since I really don't like the idea of having an inline code no matter how efficient or faster it might be. Also, it might be easier for you to understand, and no library imports are required.

**CODE:**

```
mylist = [('dog', 'camel'), ('horse'), ('List_of_people_saved_by_Oskar'), 'mouse_bear', 'lion tiger rabbit', 'ant']
new_list = []

for items in mylist:
    if type(items) == tuple:
        for animals in items:
            new_list.append(animals)
    elif '_' in items:
        new_animal = items.split('_')
        for animals in new_animal:
            new_list.append(animals)

    elif ',' in items:
        new_animal = items.split(',')
        for animals in new_animal:
            new_list.append(animals)

    elif ' ' in items:
        new_animal = items.split(' ')
        for animals in new_animal:
            new_list.append(animals)
    else:
        new_list.append(items)
print(new_list)
```

**Output:**

```
['dog', 'camel', 'horse', 'List', 'of', 'people', 'saved', 'by', 'Oskar', 'mouse', 'bear', 'lion', 'tiger', 'rabbit', 'ant']
```